# parsing error at line 17 how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, adobe, dreamweaver

It is showing parsing error on line 17 I have thoroughly checked it but unable to find error.So how do I fix this error.it is insert_city_query.php

```
<?php
    include('../../Connections/autodealers.php');
    //error_reporting(0);
    $cityname=$_POST['cityname'];
    $cityorder=$_POST['cityorder'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    if($status="Enabled")
    $status=1;
    else
    $status=0;

    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$db_prefix."city (cityname,cityorder,status) values
    (
    '" . addslashes($cityname) . "' ,
    '" . addslashes($cityorder) . "' ,
    '" . addslashes($status) . " '  
    WHERE LCASE='strtolower($_REQUEST['cityname'])')";
    echo $query;
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result)
    {
    die ('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
    header("Location: " .$base_url. "admin/city_insert.php" );//if query fails
    }
    else
    {
    header("Location: " .$base_url. "admin/cities.php" );//if query suceeds
    }
    mysql_close($autodealers);



    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$db_prefix."city (cityname,cityorder,status) values
('" . addslashes($cityname) . "' ,
'" . addslashes($cityorder) . "' ,
'" . addslashes($status) . " '  
WHERE LCASE='" . strtolower($_REQUEST['cityname']) . "')";
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**Warning**: The query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value (*s*) of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `strtolower()` as a function.

You should change this line:

```
WHERE LCASE='strtolower($_REQUEST['cityname'])')";
```

to

```
WHERE LCASE='".strtolower($_REQUEST['cityname'])."')";
```